# How to edit child pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way to edit child pages like `mywebsite.com/page/childpage`
 in wordpress. Actually i want to edit product category page in woocommerce. I want to add a div on the top of product catogery page. I am searching for this since 2 days on google but i didn't  get solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add this div to all category pages (i.e. http://yourwebsite.com/product-category/category-name/) then you need to edit the `archive-product.php` template. It is located at `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates`, but **don't** edit it there!

Create `woocommerce` folder in your theme's folder and copy the file there, then edit. It will overwrite the default template and will be safe for Woocommerce updates, since they won't overwrite this folder. If you edit it in the original path you might loose your code with the next update.

Here's a [link to details](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) on this.

And if you want to edit the description for a specific category, you can do it in the admin panel under Products > Categories.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy....    You solved a big problem of mine. A big big big tanks to you.